# Any way to change enddate of trial campaigns in Adwords API?

Tags: api, google-ads-api, trial

I want to use the Adwords API to change the endDate of a Trial Campaign. I am aware that the simple SET operation of the endDate is not allowed for trials (its not really clear to me why as it can be easily changed in interface and editor).

The only API solution I came up with is

1. End experiment
2. Create new Draft
3. Create new Trial

However, I am wondering if you know any way to circumvent this (imho) unnecessary restriction by the Adwords API and modify the endDate of an existing trial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is: Use the TrialService not the CampaignService.